# To match today's Date as Condition for sending email reminders

Tags: google-apps-script

I have used the mentioned script 2 times earlier to send email reminders based on a condition based on a specific text in a column. But when I am trying to modify the condition in terms of date then its not working.There is next follow up date in col T, which is 19th col. I want to check if nextfollowup date matches today's date,if yes then combined the relevant rows and send reminder through email. Executive Email is in K column which is 6th col. Filled by Executive column is in F which is 6th.
I tried different methods but got no result. Hence requesting your help.

Below is the script and column names

**Existing Script

```
function nextFollowup() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TGE Next Follow up");
var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange("A1:BL" + lastRow);
var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
var headers = dataValues[0];

// Calculate today's date
var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString;
//var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");

// Group data by sales executives
var groupedData = {};
for (var i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
var row = dataValues[i];
var salesExecEmail = row[6]; // Assuming sales executives' emails are in column G
var execName = row[5]; // Assuming sales executives' names are in column F
var condition1 = row[19].toLocaleString; // Assuming column T is 19th column
var condition2 = row[1] ? new Date(row[1]).toLocaleDateString() : ""; // Assuming column B is        
var condition3 = row[3]; // Assuming column D is 4th column
var condition4 = row[8]; // Assuming column I is 9th column
var condition5 = row[9]; // Assuming column J is 10th column
var condition6 = row[16]; // Assuming column Q is 17th column
var condition7 = row[20]; // Assuming column U is 21st column
var condition8 = row[25]; // Assuming column Z is 26th column
var condition9 = row[26]; // Assuming column AA is 27th column

if (condition1 === today) {
  if (!groupedData[salesExecEmail]) {
    groupedData[salesExecEmail] = { name: execName, data: [] };
  }
groupedData[salesExecEmail].data.push([condition2, condition3,condition4,condition5,


condition6,condition7,condition8,condition9]);                                                                                  
  //Logger.log(condition1);
}
}

// Sending reminder emails
for (var execEmail in groupedData) {
var execName = groupedData[execEmail].name;
var execData = groupedData[execEmail].data;
var emailBody = "<html><body><p>Dear " + execName + ",</p>";
emailBody += "<p>Here are your pending leads for " + formattedDate + ":</p>";
emailBody += "<table border='1'><tr>";

// Add headers
   emailBody += "<th>" + headers[1] + "</th><th>" + headers[3] + "</th><th>" + headers[8] + "  

   </th>   <th>" + headers[9] + "</th><th>" + headers[16] + "</th><th>" + headers[20] + "  
   </th><th>" + headers[25] + "</th><th>" + headers[26] + "</th></tr>";

// Add data rows
for (var j = 0; j < execData.length; j++) {
  var rowData = execData[j];
  emailBody += "<tr>";
  for (var k = 0; k < rowData.length; k++) {
    emailBody += "<td>" + rowData[k] + "</td>";
  }
  emailBody += "</tr>";
}
emailBody += "</table></body></html>";

// Send email
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: execEmail,
  //cc: "", // Add the email address(es) you want to include in CC
  subject: "Pending Leads for " + execName + " For - " ,
  htmlBody: emailBody
});
}
Logger.log("Recipient email address: " + execEmail);
Logger.log("Recipient email address: " + salesExecEmail);
}

**Column Names

Record
Timestamp (This sheet)
Timestamp
Type of Inquiry
Total Inquiry
Filled by Executive
Executive Email
Executive Mobile
Person / Customer / Agent Name
Business Name
Email ID
Mobile No
Alternate Number
Location
Business Type
Company Address
Lead Type
Date of Visit
Call Type
Next Follow Up Date
Sales Stage
Comment / Remarks
No. of Adult
No. of Kids
No. of Sr. Citizens
```